# Validate content-length before model binding ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am wondering how I can validate the content-length BEFORE the request body is read by the model binder in ASP.NET Web Api.

I can do it in the Action but then it's a waste of resources because the stream has already been read?

```
var contentLength = Request.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
if (contentLength > 1024*1024*20)
{
     throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge);
}
```

Is it ok to do it in an Action Filter?

Comment: Request object would have already been populated by the framework.So, it would have set all the properties of Request object before any filters are applied.You can write your logic by implementing IActionFilter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your are using Owin for hosting your API, and you want to globally apply this restriction to all requests, then you could make this check in a simple Owin middleware executed before Web API in your Owin pipeline:

```
app.Use(async (c, n) =>
{
    var request = c.Request;

    if (request != null)
    {
        string[] headerValues;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValue("Content-Length", out headerValues))
        {
            var lengthValue = headerValues.First();
            if (Convert.ToInt64(lengthValue) > 1024 * 1024 * 20)
            {
                c.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    await n.Invoke();
});

//app.UseWebApi(..)
```

#### [Edit]

If you need to restrict the `Content-Length` in a more fine graded fashion, then your best option is to create an `AuthorizationFilter` that is executed **before** the model binding [in the Web API pipeline](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf), as opposed to a generic `ActionFilter`.

Something like this should work:

```
public class MaxContentLengthAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly long _maxContentType;

    public MaxContentLengthAttribute(long maxContentType)
    {
        _maxContentType = maxContentType;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var contentLength = actionContext.Request.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
        if (contentLength.HasValue && contentLength.Value > _maxContentType)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
[MaxContentLength(1024*1024*20)]
public void Post([FromBody]Foo value)
{
    DoWork(value);
}
```

This way you can respond to the request before the content is read by the model-binder.

Comment: Not using Owin and I don't want it to be globally applied, just action specific.